# How to skip pause in batch file

Tags: batch-file

In a Windows batch file, myScript.bat runs otherScript.bat, and in otherScript.bat, there's a pause in first line.

How can I send a keystroke thast skips the pause in myScript.bat? So my script won't need to take any extract keystroke and won't be blocked by the pause.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

One way would be to use the `echo` command to do the keystroke for you.

For example:

### myScript.bat

```
@echo OFF

@echo Calling otherScript.bat...
@echo | call otherScript.bat
@echo Done.
```

### otherScript.bat

```
pause
@echo Hello World
```

[Stefan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3583648/1536976) is more flexible and allows you to control when to pause or not, but this solution will work if you're not able to revise otherScript.bat for some reason.

Comment: Both answers are awesome, but I can't edit otherScript.bat. So accept this one.

Comment: Just the solution I was looking for +1

Comment: How can i achieve this in vbscript, in mycase "myscript.vbs". If I use the command   WshShell.Run " | call otherScript.bat",1,true     getting a error that unable to wait for process..

Comment: for some reason I didn't think that I could pipe TO a .bat file. Now I have to wonder what else I have assumed that could not be done!!

Comment: You should use `@echo. | call otherScript.bat` (note the dot after echo). That way only a new line is sent to the other script instead of the string "ECHO is on." or similar. Sending the string might have negative effect when `set /p` is used in the other script.

Answer (score 21):

You could modify otherScript.bat so that it accepts an optional parameter, telling it to skip the pause command like this:

```
if "%1"=="nopause" goto start
pause
:start
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `< NUL` instead of `echo( |`

### myScript.bat

```
@echo OFF

@echo Calling otherScript.bat...
set var=One
< NUL call otherScript.bat
@echo Done. var=%var%
```

### otherScript.bat

```
@echo off
pause
echo Hello World
set var=two
```

The main difference is, otherscript runs in the same cmd.exe instance, but `echo. | call ...` will run in a child cmd.exe.

A child instance has the problem, that otherscript can modify environment variables, but the changes are lost after the return