# Skip pause in batch file from VBScript

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript

In VBScript if `myScript.vbs` runs `otherScript.bat`, and in `otherScript.bat`, there's a `pause` statement. How can I send a keystroke to skip that pause from `myScript.vbs`? So my script won't need to take any extract keystroke and won't be blocked by the pause.

There is an answer in another thread [with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583565/how-to-skip-pause-in-batch-file) for acheving this in a batch file, but I need somthing similar in VBScript. Introducing another batch file between `myScript.vbs` and `Otherscript.bat` is one dirty solution, but is there a direct way?

Comment: Just remove the `pause` statement from the batch file?

Comment: I can only modify myScript.vbs.

Comment: perhaps running the .bat asynchronously (without wait on return) then using the `appactivate` and `sendkey` methods?